# .NET MVC не работает javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться  почему  в  моем коде  не работает  javascript script.

```
@model Invest.Models.Investment
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Invest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("ddddddd");
        $("#create").click(function () {
            if ($("#amount").val() > ($("u").text + 0)) {
                $("#err").text("ex amount of investment");
                return false;
            // $("#create").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        })
    });
</script>

<h2>Invest</h2>
    Enter value that does not exceed your amount
    (<u>@ViewBag.Available</u>)

<div id="err"></div>

<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { @id = "amount" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="create" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
}
```

Comment: Что означает "не работает"?

Comment: Например  alert  не работает,  $("#err").text("ex amount of investment"); - также не  работает. Теги <script>  имеются , здесь не отобразились.

Comment: Попробуйте его поместить в конец разметки документа.

Comment: Попробовал, нет  изменений, даже alert  не работает.

Comment: Я - не специалист по этому, но не пробовали засунуть его в секцию скриптов? Также для отладки начните с того, что оставьте один alert и уберите все обращения к элементам, а затем постепенно их добавляйте. Так будет проще определить причину.

Comment: У вас здесь   }) точка с запятой пропущена.

Comment: Попробовал, оставил  только alert,  не работает  он.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в javascript точка с запятой - опциональный элемент синтаксиса. Некоторые стайл-гайды даже рекомендуют не использовать ее, чтобы не забывать об этой опциональности.

Comment: откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите конкретную ошибку

Comment: а это у Вас случайно не PartialView?! покажите код контроллера как Вы вызываете данное представление

Comment: @Bald56rus причем тут паршел вью и не работающий JS? да и из кода видно что это обычный вью, даже с явным указанием родительского лайоута, кстати который неплохо бы вынести во вьюстарт

Comment: @Dmitry при том что если PartialView/Партиал вью(ну не как не паршел вью) то тогда скрипты надо подключать немного иначе

Comment: @Bald56rus http://wooordhunt.ru/word/partial, не поленился специально для Вас нашел ваш "партиал", послушайте как это звучит на языке оригинала. И прочтите исходный код с первых строчек

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо за ссылку, все равно не буду называть "паршел" уж лучше напишу *частичное представление*, перечитал, свой вопрос снимаю - приведенное представление не может быть частичным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте, что конструкции вида $() это jQuery, и что бы они работали, надо загрузить сам jQuery

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        });
</script>
}
```

Вот так работать будет

```
@model Invest.Models.Investment
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Invest";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <h2>Invest</h2>
        Enter value that does not exceed your amount
        (<u>@ViewBag.Available</u>)

    <div id="err"></div>

    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="create" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("ddddddd");
            $("#create").click(function () {
                if ($("#Amount").val() > ($("u").text + 0)) {
                    $("#err").text("ex amount of investment");
                    return false;
                // $("#create").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    }
```

**UPD**: исправил в JS id с #amount на #Amount

Comment: В стандартном layout @scripts и так стоит выше остального. надо такими вопросами не надо гадать. их нужно закрывать, пока автор не уточнит, что именно за ошибку он видит в консоли, или не приведет полный код, включая layout.

Comment: при создании проекта секция в лайоуте болтается внизу перез закрытием документа, у топикстартера выполнения скрипта стояло выше загрузки библиотек. но любая ошибка внутри функции конечно же приведет к невыполнению всей функции, тут я согласен

Comment: Спасибо, таким  образом алерт  работает  при загрузке документа,  но  не работает при  событии change  текстбокса. Я  создал  такой скрипт :
             <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("d");

        $("#amount").change(function ()
        {
                        alert("dadasdsadsadsada");

     
         $("#create").prop("disabled", true);
    

          });

    });
</script>

Comment: Второй  алерт  не работает  после изменения текстбокса.

Comment: @Dmitry опять они все поменяли :) но все равно, похоже, стоит подсказать топикастеру, как пользоваться консолью и отладчиком :(

Comment: Я  использую  мозиллу,  так  она  даже инпут  не показывает  в html  разметке, не  знаю  ,как  отлаживать  правильно в консоли.

Comment: @PashaPash ага, раньше в хедер все грузилось, а теперь скрипты в низ а стили как и правильно в хедере остались

Comment: @Maks используйте хром, там хоть фаербаг и попроще но все остальное получше

Comment: @Maks <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { alert("d"); $("#amount").on('change',function () { alert("dadasdsadsadsada"); $("#create").prop("disabled", true); }); }); </script>

Comment: @PashaPash а еще топикстартеру надо подсказать что в JS #Amount != #amount

Comment: Да, вы правы,  я малоопытен,еще, подумал, что этим  поменял  id -@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { @id = "amount" }),  а он  остался Amount. Спасибо, за помощь, вроде всё  понятно теперь.

Comment: @Maks если мой ответ решил вашу проблему не забудте поставить галочку ;)

Comment: У меня вроде еще репутация  не позволяет.)

Comment: @Maks на это репутация точно не влияет ;)

Comment: Да, это  моя внимательность влияет, не  увидел галочку)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать так, без указания `@section Scripts{}`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("ddddddd");            
    });
</script>
```

Comment: секция нужна для того, чтоб указать разору в каком месте нужно отрендрить код внутри секции